# Excel 2010 calculates when nothing changed

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 workbook that insists on "calculating" every time I enter, then exit a cell (blank) even when nothing is changed.

If the above workbook is open it spreads the problem to any other workbook is that is open. Problem will disappear when the above workbook is closed.

The problematic workbook contains 3 Sheets; 
1 has a table that pulls external data with an SQL command, 
2 has various formulas that summarise the data from Sheet 1, 
3 has various graphs that use data from Sheet2.

The problematic workbook contains no macros.

I've searched Google high and low to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: Look for the obvious suspects:  **Indirect()**, **Offset()**, **Today()**, **Now()**, etc.

Comment: Add [ADDRESS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89) to the above list of **volatile** functions. In most cases, a volatile formula can be replaced with a non-volatile one. Find examples of the volatile formulas and edit your question to include them. Alternatives may be available.

Comment: Thanks guys, problem was Today(), will keep volatile functions in mind in the future and now the hunt for a non-volatile version of Today()

Comment: I don't think you will find a non-volatile direct replacement for the [TODAY functoin](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566) but you could set a cell to today's date with one of the workbook event macros and reference that cell throughout your workbook. Calculation cycle would only be slowed every time the event was triggered. Too may different possible events to detail here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As the [TODAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566) is considered a volatile¹ function, it isn't wise to use it repeatedly within long columns and/or rows of formulas, particularly within calculation-intensive array formulas. Calculation lag can quickly build up and the function's volatile nature will force a calculation cycle whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that actually affects its outcome changes as is the norm with non-volatile functions.

A formula based defined name that does not actually refer to any worksheet call is a good fit here. Using something like `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY()))` is counterproductive because you have not removed the volatile TODAY() function. However, VBA can write a hardcoded native worksheet function into the **RefersTo:** of the defined name. In this case, the current date will be constructed using the worksheets' [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29).

> The following code belongs in the **ThisWorkbook** code page. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, locate **ThisWorkbook** in the **Project Explorer**. If the project explorer is not visible, tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or use the pull-down menus to choose View ► Project Explorer.
>
> [image: ThisWorkbook Code sheet]
>
> Double-click **ThisWorkbook** or right-click and choose **View Code**. Paste the following into the code sheet titled something like **Book1 - ThisWorkbook (Code)**.

```
Private Const dnCURRENT As String = "Current"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'force a Workbook_SheetChange on open to check Current date
    Call Workbook_SheetChange(Worksheets(1), Worksheets(1).Cells(1))
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo no_Current
    With ThisWorkbook.Names(dnCURRENT)
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        If Application.Evaluate(.RefersTo) <> Date Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .RefersTo = "=DATE(" & Year(Date) & ", " & Month(Date) & ", " & Day(Date) & ")"
        End If
    End With

GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
no_Current:
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=dnCURRENT, _
                           RefersTo:="=DATE(" & Year(Date) & ", " & Month(Date) & ", " & Day(Date) & ")", _
                           Visible:=True
    Resume
bm_Safe_Exit:
    If CBool(Err.Number) Then _
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

If you wish to change the name of the defined name, do so in the private constant variable declaration at the top. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).

The first time that any change is made on any worksheet, a new defined name with workbook scope will be created called **Current**. It will have a RefersTo: with a hardcoded [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29) that returns the current system date (e.g. `=DATE(2015, 10, 14)`). If the current date is not equal to the defined names value returned by that formula, a new formula is written using the current date and this forces a new workbook-wide calculation cycle on all formulas that reference the defined name.

The defined name **Current** is a direct replacement for anywhere that the TODAY() function can be used. In practise, the formula(s) involving **Current** will only be recalculated once per day. The following image demonstrates how it will appear as an option as you start to type it into a formula.

[image: Defined Name with Formula in native worksheet formula]

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>